# Symbol's value as variable is void:company-c-headers

Tags: c++, emacs

I am trying to use [tuhdo's](https://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html) c++ IDE guide and when I try to set up company-c-headers I encounter and error which says that Symbol's value as variable is void:company-c-headers-path-system. I'm not sure what is wrong with my init file. I have looked everywhere for solutions, none of them seem to be what I'm looking for and I followed his guide.Here is my init file.

```
;;autocomplete company
(require 'company)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(setq company-backends (delete 'company-semantic company-backends))
(define-key c-mode-map  [(tab)] 'company-complete)
(define-key c++-mode-map  [(tab)] 'company-complete)
;;company-c-headers

(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-c-headers)
(add-to-list 'company-c-headers-path-system "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`company-c-headers` is not *autoloaded* you have to

```
(require 'company-c-headers)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it no longer gives me an error.